# Modify query output in BIRT using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, eclipse, reporting, birt

In BIRT, using JavaScript, I want to read a parameter passed from a webpage and, based on it being a particular value, display a modified query.

Is the following code correct ? And where do i place this ? (which event)

```
importPackage( Packages.javax.servlet.http );
importPackage( org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.script );
httpServletReq = reportContext.getHttpServletRequest( );
param=httpServletReq.getQueryString( );
if( param.indexof( "All") != -1) {
  queryText = "select CLASSIC.PRODUCTLINES.PRODUCTLINE,                 
  CLASSICMODELS.PRODCTLINES.TEXTDESCRIPTION from CLASSIC.PRODUCTLINES";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct place is your Data Set `beforeOpen` event.

Instead of `queryText` use `this.queryText`. In a Data Set context, `this` refers to that Data Set object and its properties.

And setting parameters using `httpServletRequest` seems strange to me. Why not to use native BIRT report parameters?

```
if (params["All"].value != null) {
    this.queryText = "select ...";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton ! Works perfectly. Also, if i can get a resource from where i could study scripting for Birt, it would be reallly helpful. Thanks.